# Problem with adding textView and editView as double and displaying it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to take a value from editText and from textView and add it together and display it. When I am trying to do it i get an error:

> `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:`

However, when I am doing it separately it works, the problem is when I am adding. Sorry for hard coding.

```
 if (position == 1 && editTextBillAmount.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                       textViewMeal.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString())));
                       textViewTipAmount.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString()) * .10));
                        textViewFull.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString()+df.format(Double.parseDouble(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString()) * .10))));
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "10%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: Double.parseDouble throws a NumberFormatException when you call it with a value that doesn't properly parse into a double (i.e. fully numeric with a decimal point or some other more complex variations involving exponents).  Empty string being a value that does not properly parse into a double (it throws this exception).

More than likely some of the text fields are currently empty (resulting in the `For input string:`) so that when this snippet of code is called, it throws a NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are multiplying .10 with a string which gave you that error. well problem will be solved if you calculate it in another variables and then put it into your results. hope it will be solved.et me know it it works, otherwise I will share the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

If not is necessary a format for the Double you can use this:

```
    textViewMeal.setText(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString());
    textViewTipAmount.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString()) * .10));
    textViewFull.setText(String.valueOf( Double.parseDouble(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString()) + (Double.parseDouble(editTextBillAmount.getText().toString()) * .10)));
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "10%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if is necessary a format for the Double, check that the string into the editTextBillAmount have the correct format